# object returning old state

Tags: react-native

I want to return current state in function, which is returning object.

```
myFunction = () => {
        return (
            myObject = {
                object: this.state.variable
            }
        )
    }
```

```
render() {
   return (

    <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() => {this.setState({ variable: 2 }),  () => console.log(myFunction())}>

    </TouchableOpacity> )                   
}
```

Function is returning state, which was default. I want to return new state, which was setted.

Comment: where are you calling myFunction? Can we see more of your code, please?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh just updated

Comment: It's just a typo. It should be `this.setState({ variable: 2 },  () => console.log(myFunction()))` (note the position of the parentheses, the callback function must be a parameter to setState.)

Comment: Yes, that's correct...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
render() {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
        this.setState({ variable: 2 },  
        ()=>console.log(this.myFunction()));
    }>

    </TouchableOpacity> )                   
}
```

Comment: This won't work, as setState is async so it's supposed to be `this.setState({variable:2},()=>console.log(this.myFunction())`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
render() {
   return (
    <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() => {
         const value = 2;
         this.setState({ variable: value }); 
         console.log(myFunction(value);
       }
    }></TouchableOpacity>
   )                   
}
```

```
myFunction = (value) => {
  return (
    myObject = {
      object: value,
    },
  ),
}
```